# MarkerClusterer - cluster by counties

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

let's say I have a JSON object like this:

```
{
"county1": [{
    "city_markers": [
        {
            "latlng": [49.58543,17.29932],
            "nazev": "Město Jaroměřice nad Rokytnou"
        }
    ],
    "orp_markers": [
        {
            "latlng": [49.56406,16.95874],
            "nazev": "Město Třebíč (ORP)"
        }
    ],
    "region_markers": [
        {
            "latlng": [49.52842,17.59595],
            "nazev": "Místo 1"
        }
    ],
    "levelmeter_markers": [
        {
            "latlng": [49.75607,17.50806],
            "nazev": "Místo 2"
        }
    ],
    "rainmeter_markers": [
        {
            "latlng": [49.80573,17.20044],
            "nazev": "Místo 3"
        }
    ]
}],
"county2": [{
    "city_markers": [
        {
            "latlng": [49.67083,17.99145],
            "nazev": "Město Jaroměřice nad Rokytnou"
        }
    ],
    "orp_markers": [
        {
            "latlng": [49.61391,18.02441],
            "nazev": "Město Třebíč (ORP)"
        }
    ],
    "region_markers": [
        {
            "latlng": [49.93319,17.61792],
            "nazev": "Místo 1"
        }
    ],
    "levelmeter_markers": [
        {
            "latlng": [49.50702,18.39795],
            "nazev": "Místo 2"
        }
    ],
    "rainmeter_markers": [
        {
            "latlng": [49.93319,17.29932],
            "nazev": "Místo 3"
        }
    ]
}]
}
```

I have counties 1 to 14 and I would like to create a cluster for each of them. At the same time, I need to keep record of objects in different counties (city_markers etc.) so when user wants to hide city_markers, he clicks the button and they disappear. If he clicks again, they reappear. Right now I use an array fo each type of marker and in the end I push them to the markerclusterer. When user wants to hide a certain type, I loop through the array and remove markers from the clusterer.
I know how to keep record of each type of markers, but I have no idea how to create the cluster for each county. I don't think that defining 14 arrays more is a good way to go.